# how to replace locked dll (was inuse)

Tags: windows, dll

I have a dll loaded into LSASS. I need to replace it on reboot.

There is an old utility called inuse from win2k reskit. It does not seem to work anymore (I am on windows 7)

Anybody know the right way to do it now?

Comment: How was your DLL loaded into LSASS? You shouldn't unload it without LSASS's co-operation -- LSASS is one process you definitely don't want to destabilise.

Comment: right - thats why i want to replace the dll on reboot

Answer (score 1):

Movefile from Sysinternals should do the trick :)

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556

Comment: does not work on windows 7. pendmoves says its pending, after reboot pendmoves says its not pending anymore but the file did not get changed

Answer (score 0):

Copying system dlls on Windows 7 (and Vista) is described in [System File Checker tool article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929833/en-us?fr=1) (in "Step2: If the System File Checker tool cannot repair a file").

Here is a quick (almost copy&paste) solution:

```
REM you will need to change this :-)
SET tmpset_SOURCE=c:\Windows\SysWOW64\d3d10_1.dll
SET tmpset_DEST=c:\_tmp\SysWOW64\d3d10_1.dll

REM copy and paste this straight to cmd:
takeown /f %tmpset_DEST%
icacls %tmpset_DEST% /GRANT %USERNAME%:F
copy %tmpset_SOURCE% %tmpset_DEST%
```